# TFS integration with Octopus Deploy

Tags: tfs, octopus-deploy

I am trying to build my packages using TFS, already integrated with octopus server so that the package can be pulled to octopus server afterwards and get deployed automatically.Created a build definition to build db and windows packages. it goes successful for db however stuck in case of windows where it is supposed to create a release for its deployment.Error -:
There was a problem with your request.
 - Release '20170808.12' already exists for this project. Please use a different version, or look at using a mask to auto-increment the number.
Error from Octopus server (HTTP 400 BadRequest)

Could anyone please help me on it....
Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Can you share the detailed build logs?

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to a create an Octopus Deploy Release with a name which already exists.

You could adjust your version strategy through `AssemblyInfo.cs` or adjust Octopus Deploy to not use package names for Releases for under **Octopus** -> **Project** -> **Settings**

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the Release '20170808.12' already exists.

According to the description in [this article](http://help.octopusdeploy.com/discussions/questions/5177-auto-increment-release-number), it should be an Octopus Deploy issue.

Which version of Octopus Deploy do you use? If you are using the old version, just trying update to the latest version.

In addition, you can try to use below **Create release options** to check if that works:

```
--ignoreexisting   If a release with the version number already 
                   exists, ignore it

--force [Optional] If a project is configured to skip
                   packages with already-installed versions,
                   override this setting to force re-deployment
                   (flag, default false).
```

Also try to create a release with a specified release number:

```
octo create-release --project HelloWorld --version 1.0.3 --server http://octopus/ --apiKey API-ABCDEF123456
```

See [creating-releases](https://octopus.com/docs/api-and-integration/octo.exe-command-line/creating-releases) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Andy for your response.